# React Native support for tooltip

Tags: react-native, tooltip

Not able to find the answer anywhere, does react native support tooltips or iOS and Android?
I need tooltip on longpress on a button, but not finding any relevant info.

I did see third party libraries, and it seems offical RN doesnt doesn't support it. Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use share with uncommented prop `anchor` or modal with `presentationStyle` props :)